# Why my numpy Neural Network doesnt converge when the loss is "Mean Squared Error "?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-networks

I build a MLP with numpy to approximate the cosine function, when the loss is Mean error it converge:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(0)

X_min = -10
X_max = 10
X = np.linspace(X_min, X_max, 10_000).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.cos(X).reshape(-1, 1)
X = (X - X_min) / (X_max - X_min) -0.5

# Split dataset into training and testing sets

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)



class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
        self.layer_sizes = layer_sizes
        self.num_layers = len(layer_sizes)
        self.learning_rate = 0.01

        # Initialize weights and biases for all layers except input layer
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(layer_sizes[i-1], layer_sizes[i]) for i in range(1, self.num_layers)]
        self.biases = [np.zeros((1, layer_sizes[i])) for i in range(1, self.num_layers)]

    def forward(self, X):
        self.activations = [X]  # Store activations for all layers
        output = X
        for w, b in zip(self.weights, self.biases):
            output = np.dot(output, w) + b
            output = np.tanh(output)  # Activation function (tanh in this case)
            self.activations.append(output)
        self.output = output

    def backward(self, X, y):
        m = X.shape[0]
        # Compute gradients
        delta = (self.output - y)**1
        #print(delta.shape)
        moyenne = np.mean(delta)
        delta =  np.repeat(moyenne, m).reshape(-1, 1)
        for i in range(self.num_layers - 1, 0, -1):
            # Compute gradients for weights and biases
            self.weights[i-1] -= self.learning_rate * (1 / m) * np.dot(self.activations[i-1].T, delta)
            self.biases[i-1] -= self.learning_rate * (1 / m) * np.sum(delta, axis=0)
            # Compute delta for previous layer
            delta = np.dot(delta, self.weights[i-1].T) * (1 - np.power(self.activations[i-1], 2))

    def train(self, X, y, epochs, batch_size=30):
        num_samples = X.shape[0]
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            for i in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
                X_batch = X[i:i+batch_size]
                y_batch = y[i:i+batch_size]
                # Forward pass
                self.forward(X_batch)
                # Backward pass
                self.backward(X_batch, y_batch)
            # Print loss every 100 epochs
            if epoch % (N_epochs//10)  == 0:
                # Use entire dataset for loss calculation
                self.forward(X)
                loss = np.mean(np.square(self.output - y))
                #loss = np.mean((self.output - y))
                print(f'Epoch {epoch}, Loss: {loss}')

# Example usage:
layer_sizes = [1, 100,100,100, 1]  # Define layer sizes including input and output layers
N_epochs = 100


model = NeuralNetwork(layer_sizes)
model.train(X_train, y_train, epochs=N_epochs, batch_size=32)



# Evaluate the model
model.forward(X_test)
test_loss = np.mean(np.square(model.output - y_test))
print(f'Test Loss: {test_loss}')

X_plot = np.linspace(X_min, X_max, 1000).reshape(-1, 1)
X_plot_2 = (X_plot - X_min) / (X_max - X_min) - 0.5
model.forward(X_plot_2)
plt.plot(np.cos(X_plot))
plt.plot(model.output)
```

However it doesnt converge when `delta = (self.output - y)**2` aka loss = Mean Squared Error

We can see the convergence can be done with tensorflow:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(0)

X_min = -10
X_max = 10
X = np.linspace(X_min, X_max, 10_000).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.cos(X).reshape(-1, 1)
X = (X - X_min) / (X_max - X_min) - 0.5


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error')


model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1)
```

Can you explain me why? Is it because of the optimizer from tensorflow?

i tried to find a way to not use any optimizer with tensorflow:

```
# Define a dummy optimizer that does nothing
dummy_optimizer = lambda lr: tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer()

# Compile the model with the dummy optimizer
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=dummy_optimizer)
```

but couldnt achieve it

Comment: These are completely different networks because the initializations and activation functions are different (at a minimum -- there are probably other important differences). There's no reason to expect them to behave the same. I don't know why you'd try to estimate a neural network without using an optimizer. That's like trying to build a car without an engine.